# Using the same rules for jQuery validation and server-side validation

Tags: jquery, json, validation

Since the rules that the user sees should be the same rules that the server uses, I want to store validation rules in a JSON file and load them for both cases.

However, the jQuery validation plugin seems to use settings that are not valid JSON, such as

```
$('form').validate( {
    rules : {
        userid : {
            required : true,
            maxlength : 20
        }
    }
});
```

Note how none of the keys or string values are double quoted.  This makes my server-side JSON parser sad.  What can I do so that I only have to maintain one set of rules?

My idea is that when the request is actually sent to the server, my server (Java servlet in my case) will open the json file that has the `rules` variable and parse it, so that it knows what logic to apply to the posted parameters, and whether to accept or reject them.

However, the JSON specs do not allow for unquoted keys and values like javascript arrays do, so I can't store the rules as they would normally be for just jQuery use.

Comment: What happens if you store the properly-formatted file on the server, and then use jQuery.getJSON() to fetch it? Can you pass the resulting variable to the validate() function and have it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While JavaScript literals are not always valid JSON, JSON is always a valid JavaScript expression. You can use it:

```
$('form').validate( {"rules":{"userid":{"required":true,"maxlength":20}}} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Valid json is a subset of the Javascript object literal syntax. Basically,

```
{
    key1: 2,
    key2: true
}
```

is identical to:

```
{
    "key1": 2,
    "key2": true
}
```

Literal numbers, boolean values and null are specific values in JSON, so if your parser chokes on them, then your parser is incorrect.

You can use "JSON" in Javascript.

JSON is in fact JavaScript Object Notation, it is explicitly designed to be valid Javascript, to the point that the idea was that worst-case scenario was you could use eval to parse it. JQuery doesn't use a particular syntax, it just wants a specifically **structured** object, it isn't a map, there is no concept of string keys in javascript objects, just members that are valid identifiers, and members that are not.

If you had a field named people-seen, then you would enter that rule into the validator like this:

```
{ "people-seen": {
   required: true
}}
```